Syn dependency when trying to use maturin on a Mac
I am trying to follow the quickstart of maturin. However, after creating a project and copying the Cargo.toml over I always get this issue when I run cargo build.
> cargo build
warning: unused manifest key: build-system
warning: unused manifest key: tool
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `syn = "^2.0.59"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 2.0.56, 2.0.55, 2.0.54, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `pyo3-macros-backend v0.23.1`
    ... which is depended on by `pyo3-macros v0.23.1`
    ... which is depended on by `pyo3 v0.23.1`
    ... which is depended on by `guessing-game v0.1.0 (/Users/vincent/Development/guessing-game)`

I tried installing rust (I had a version locally that was multiple years old at this point) but it did not help. Google also did not return anything useful. Anybody know

It works just fine for me. Did you run cargo update in your project after updating rust? I am asking, because syn 2.0.56 is the last version with MSRV v.1.56.0.

It turned out that I was using a version of Rust that was simply too old. Moving my code to Github codespaces immediately fixed everything and so did upgrading my local setup.
